# google maps flutter my location blue dot compass arrow

Tags: flutter, google-maps

update question:
I am facing a problem when using google map flutter.
Normally in the google map application, the current position will be displayed with a blue dot and trimmed beam, but in google_maps_flutter, it will display a blue dot and an arrow indicating the direction of the compass. currently when i rotate my phone the beam on google maps app moves in the direction of the phone but the arrow on the app using google_maps_flutter doesn't move or moves very slow and wrong direction. everyone can test it with the example of google maps flutter below. Has anyone encountered this problem can give me advice or a keyword to solve. Thank you everyone for reading.

if anyone wants to try can pull directly from google_maps_flutter example. Install on device -> settings -> enable GPS permission -> open app -> user interface -> mylocation marker. tks

link git hub example:

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter

blue and compass arrow in google_map_flutter
[image: blue and compass arrow in google_map_flutter]

blue dot and the beam that indicates in Google Maps application
[image: blue dot and the beam that indicates in Google Maps application]

Answer (score 1):

This button is provided by the Google Maps Flutter plugin directly. I think, it is there for compatibility reasons and it does not play well with other widgets wich are overlapping the map and it is not customizable, as far as I know.

My suggestion is to disable this button and use your own buttons to control the GoogleMaps widget. Use [Floating Action Buttons](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FloatingActionButton-class.html) for example.

Comment: Looks like you are misunderstanding my question. i am having problem with the compass arrow front in the blue dot the current location. I have updated the question hope you can review it. many tks

Comment: Now I understand the problem, thanks for clarification. Unfortunately, I do not know whether you can modify the marker for your current position using the `google_maps_flutter` plugin. Some other maps plugins might provide this feature, though.